# Developing first Firefox extension, how to include js?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am developing a simple Firefox (v 26) extension which overlays the "BrowserToolbarPalette" and simply adds a Button to the main toolbar.

The "oncommand=" listener for the button is working when I use inline javascript such as:

```
<overlay id="xulschoolhello-browser-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">


  <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton id="NodeVisButton"
               tooltiptext="Visualize Server Nodes"
               label="NodeVis" 
               oncommand="alert('Foobar');" />
  </toolbarpalette>
</overlay>
```

...and the alert is showing up.

If I include my js file like this:

```
<overlay id="xulschoolhello-browser-overlay"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

  <script type="application/x-javascript" src="chrome://nodevisualizer/content/nodevis.js" />

  <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
    <toolbarbutton id="NodeVisButton"
               tooltiptext="Visualize Server Nodes"
               label="NodeVis" 
               oncommand="nodeVis.showNode()" />
  </toolbarpalette>
</overlay>
```

...the javascript is not working.

Content of the javascript file:

```
var nodeVis = {
    showNode: function {
            alert('Argh!');
    }
};
```

My chrome.manifest:

```
content     nodevisualizer    chrome/content/

overlay chrome://browser/content/browser.xul chrome://nodevisualizer/content/plugin.xul
```

..and my directory layout:

```
node_visualizer
  - chrome
      -- content
         --- plugin.xul
         --- nodevis.js
  - chrome.manifest
  - install.rdf
```

At some point I managed to get the javascript console to at least show an error that "nodeVis" is not defined, but not in the current layout/config.

Any help appriciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Darn it, there was a typo in the javascript with missing parenthesis behind "function {}".

```
var nodeVis = {
    showNode: function (){
            alert('Argh!');
    }
};
```

. Anyways. Now we have a nice template to fiddle around.